# function only display first database entry. android, sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite, show

I am trying to use some data from my database, but function only use data from first entry. What should I add to go through all the entries from database?

```
public void drawdayplan(){

DatabaseConnector dbConnector = new DatabaseConnector(Clock.this);

       Intent a = getIntent();
        String d_m_y = a.getStringExtra("d_m_y");
       dbConnector.open();
       Cursor result =  dbConnector.gethour(d_m_y); 

       if(result.moveToFirst()){

               int hourfromIndex = result.getColumnIndex("inthourfrom");
               int hourtoIndex = result.getColumnIndex("inthourto");
               int colourIndex = result.getColumnIndex("colour");
              hourfrom = result.getInt(hourfromIndex);
              hourto = result.getInt(hourtoIndex);
              colour = result.getString(colourIndex);

            // here are some steps with painting which are using this variables 

            }

      }

       result.close();

       dbConnector.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But function only use data from first entry.

You never ask for more than the first row. Call `moveToNext()` in a loop like this:

```
while(result.moveToNext()){
    // Read each row
}
```